# Could not load assembly or file xxx or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created asp.net application where some project in vb.net and some in in c#.net. I have referred c# project DLL in vb.net project which working fine in local environment but when I deployed on server I’m getting error while accessing application url as

> Could not load assembly or file xxx or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

xxx as c# code DLL which is referred in vb.net project for both we have created nuget packages and referred in respective application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.